# Fluent validation: How to customize the bad request message format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

In my controller, i have put a check:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

This gives me error is specific format, for example:

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "stocks.SellerType": [
      "SellerType should be greater than 101"
    ],
    "stocks.SourceId": [
      "SourceId should be less than 300"
    ]
  }
}
```

How can i customize this error message format. I know how to customize the error messages i.e. "SourceId should be less than 300". But i have no clue how can i change "Message", remove or rename json field "ModelState"?

Comment: a wrapper which will return a smaller ModelState would be OK for you ? eg: your own custom Object with Message (and other fields, if necessary)

Comment: yes i want my own custom object.

Comment: Where you are getting this error, on `controller` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: to change default message and keep default formatting for `ModelState` errors you can use `HttpError` class:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
        new HttpError(ModelState, includeErrorDetail: true)
        {
            Message = "Custom mesage"
        });
}
```

Or you can define your own model for validation result and return it with required status code (to rename json field "ModelState"). For example:

```
class ValdationResult
{
    public string Message { get; }
    public HttpError Errors { get; }

    public ValdationResult(string message, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        Message = message;
        Errors = new HttpError(modelState, includeErrorDetail: true).ModelState;
    }
}
...

if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 
        new ValdationResult("Custom mesage", ModelState));
}
```

Comment: Hi, Tried it and I got ugly serialization with k__BackingField ? {"Message":"The request is invalid.","Errors":{"netMonthly":{"_errors":[{"<Exception>k__BackingField":null,"<ErrorMessage>k__BackingField":"error message"}],"<Value>k__BackingField":null}}}

Comment: @LeszekRepie, you're right. That was just example how to return custom response with status code `BadRequest`. See updated answer - default formatting will be preserved.